# How to display current month and next month dates in php?

Tags: php, html, date, datetime

I have a php code as shown below in which the calendar changes after every two months.

(a) When the current month is `January or February`, it displays all the dates for `January` and `February` (in readonly mode). 
(b) When the current month is `March or April`, it displays all the dates for `March` and `April` (in readonly mode). 
(c) And so on..

**php odd month and even month functions:**

```
<!-- odd month -->
<?php
function buildDateSelectionOdd($month)
{
    # array will hold our months
    $months = array();
    # determine whether we have an odd or even month number
    if ($month % 2 == 0) {
        # even month is always the second
        # so add the one before $month and $month itself
        $months[] = str_pad(($month - 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $months[] = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    } else {
        # for odd ones add $month and $month + 1
        $months[] = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $months[] = str_pad(($month + 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    # will hold our HTML
    $output = '';

    # got our months now, let's iterate over them
    $year = date('Y');

    foreach ($months as $index => $month) {
        if ($index == 0) {
            echo "Index 0 is ";
            print_r($month);
            # create timestamp for the first of a month
            # then get number of days for that month
            $numberOfDaysOddMonth = date('t', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));

            # we can now loop over the days and fill the output string
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfDaysOddMonth; $i++) {
                $output .= '<div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
    <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date-odd-month" name="house_sitting_date_odd_month[]" readonly="readonly" value="' . $year . '-' . $month . '-' . str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . '">
</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

?>

<!-- even month -->
<?php
function buildDateSelectionEven($month)
{    
    # array will hold our months
    $months = array();
    # determine whether we have an odd or even month number
    if ($month % 2 == 0) {
        # even month is always the second
        # so add the one before $month and $month itself
        $months[] = str_pad(($month - 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $months[] = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    } else {
        # for odd ones add $month and $month + 1
        $months[] = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $months[] = str_pad(($month + 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    # will hold our HTML
    $output = '';

    # got our months now, let's iterate over them
    $year = date('Y');

    foreach ($months as $index => $month) {
        if ($index == 1) {
            echo "Index 1 is ";
            print_r($month);
            # create timestamp for the first of a month
            # then get number of days for that month
            $numberOfDaysEvenMonth = date('t', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));

            # we can now loop over the days and fill the output string
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfDaysEvenMonth; $i++) {
                $output .= '<div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
    <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date-even-month" name="house_sitting_date_even_month[]" readonly="readonly" value="' . $year . '-' . $month . '-' . str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . '">
</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
?>
```

**html code calling odd and even month functions:**

```
<!-- Odd Month Dates START -->
<div class="sitting-days">
<h4 name="dates-selection" style="text-align:center;"><a name="dates-selection">Select Date</a>
</h4>
<?php echo buildDateSelectionOdd(date('n')); ?>
</div>
<!-- Odd Month Dates END -->


<!-- Even Month Dates START -->
<div class="sitting-days" style="margin-left:30px;">
    <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
    <div class="sitting-days">
        <?php echo buildDateSelectionEven(date('n')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Even Month Dates END -->
```

The above html code display all the dates for the odd and even month as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]
**Problem Statement:**

What I want to achieve is I want to display the current (August) and next (September)  month dates.

**1.** When the current month is `January` then the webpage should display `January` and `February` dates. 
**2.** When the current month is `February` then the webpage should display `February` and `March` dates. 
**3.** And so on..

I am wondering what changes I should make in the odd/even functions and the html code above so that it shows the current month and next month dates on the webpage meaning the screenshot should show `August` and `September` dates.

Comment: I would use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$month` and `$month+1` to the array. Then, when you're looping through the array of months, if you're at month 13 then turn that into 1 (January) and look at `$year+1`:

```
function buildDateSelectionOdd($month)
{
    # array will hold our months
    $months = [
      str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
      str_pad(($month + 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
    ];

    # will hold our HTML
    $output = '';

    # got our months now, let's iterate over them
    
    foreach ($months as $index => $month) {
        $year = date('Y');

        // Adjust month and date if necessary:
        if ( $month == 13 ) {
            $month = 1;
            $year++;
        }

        if ($index == 0) {
            echo "Index 0 is ";
            print_r($month);
            # create timestamp for the first of a month
            # then get number of days for that month
            $numberOfDaysOddMonth = date('t', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));

            # we can now loop over the days and fill the output string
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfDaysOddMonth; $i++) {
                $output .= '<div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
    <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date-odd-month" name="house_sitting_date_odd_month[]" readonly="readonly" value="' . $year . '-' . $month . '-' . str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . '">
</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: It shows odd and even. The calendar changes after every 2 months. Read my 2 points above.

Comment: For the two points in your Problem Statement, are you using August, September and October as the exact months you want that specific behavior, or do you want that behavior for all months (August being just an example of even and September being just an example of odd)?

Comment: My apologies if I was not clear in my problem statement. I want that behaviour for the all the months. When the current month is January, then the webpage should display January and February dates, When the current month is February, then the webpage should display February and March dates and so on.

Comment: What happens in December? Do you want just December, or December of the current year and January of next year?

Comment: Yes, correct.  When it's `December`, I want `December` of the current year and `January` of the next year.

Comment: Hi, I saw your answer. It looks good. Thanks for the help. I've copied all the code in the fiddle. I changed the function name to `buildDateSelection($month)` as I will be using only one function now instead of two functions. Also, in the fiddle there are two divs. 1st div corresponds to dates in the 1st column and 2nd div corresponds to dates in the 2nd column. 1st div shows current month dates and 2nd div shows next month dates. In the 2nd div, I've mentioned `date('n')+1` because I want next month. Let me know if everything looks good

Comment: @user1950349 I don't see the Fiddle so I can't say if it's right.

Comment: Looks good to me. I tested it by replacing `date('n')` with 12 and `date('n')+1` with 13 to simulate what happens when it's currently December. The dates in "current month" show up as December (12) and the dates in "next month" show up as January (1). The only thing you might want to change is adding leading zeros before 1-digit months and days, but I don't know if that's necessary.

Comment: Sounds good. I tested the code and the leading zero is already present for 1-digit months and days.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider [marking it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks!

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691611/how-to-allow-the-2nd-user-to-take-over-when-the-1st-user-is-logged-in). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateTime` since it will automatically factor dates based on a DateIneterval passed to it's `->add` or `->sub` method. The interval passed is a String that starts with `P` for period, followed by how many and `'M'`, `'D'`, or `'Y'`, for most cases.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver'); // set PHP timezone before headers
$date = new DateTime; $thisMonth = $date->format('F');
$nextMonth = $date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'))->format('F');
?>
```

Comment: You should explain *why* and *how* this answer their question

Comment: @StackSlave Hi, I am wondering if you can let me know what changes I should make in the odd and even functions above so that the html code should display current month and next month.

Comment: We can treat odd month function as current month function and even month function as next month function.

Comment: I would use AJAX. It's a way of life.

Comment: `if(DateTimeInstace->format('n') % 2 === 0){ /* even */ }else{ /* odd */ }`... and you need to do this stuff yourself. I'm just trying to help out... not do your work for you.